# How I can do event with two clicks using python add-in wizard?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, python-toolbox

How I can do event with two clicks using python add-in wizard, I have found a way to do event with one click by adding a New Tool in the wizard, but I need  "first click To copy the attributes from the features and in the second to update another feature"?  Can I use (`def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift)`) twice on the same tool?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, you could do it by adding a global variable that keeps track of your clicks. For example:

```
class ToolClass2(object):
"""Implementation for Test_addin.tool (Tool)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.shape = "NONE"
    global clickCount
    clickCount = 0
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
    global clickCount
    if clickCount == 0:
        # Your code for the first click
        clickCount = 1
    elif clickCount == 1:
        # Your code for the second click
        clickCount = 0 # Resets to first click behaviour after every second click
```

Have you also considered using left click for the first action, and then right click for the second? Or a key combination with the click? Because those are also possible options to achieve multiple actions with one tool.

See the [ESRI documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tool/014p00000027000000/) for options regarding mouse buttons and keyboard keys.